# how can i check NSNumber is null?

Tags: iphone, json, mkmapview, nsnumber

```
 NSDictionary *regionDict = (NSDictionary *) region;
            NSNumber *lat = [regionDict objectForKey:@"lat"];
            //[latitude addObject:lat];
            NSNumber *lng = [regionDict objectForKey:@"lng"];
            //[longitude addObject:lng];
            NSLog(@"%@%@%@",lat,lng,titles);

            if(lat == [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.00]  && lng == [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.00])
            {
                NSLog(@"%@%@%@",lat,lng,titles);
            }
            else
            {
                CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
                coord.latitude =lat.doubleValue;
                coord.longitude =lng.doubleValue;
                MapViewAnnotation *annotation =[[MapViewAnnotation alloc]initWithTitle:titles AndCoordinate:coord];
                [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
            }
```

if condition is not satisfied because of NSNumber not check with null value.
what is the way i can check?
Tell me possible ways.. for checking null.

Comment: Where is the region dictionary coming from?  What exactly does the first NSLog print?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can check if an object is null by doing

```
if ([myObject isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
```

But if you want to check if a float boxed in a `NSNumber` is zero, you can do

```
if (lng.floatValue == 0. && lat.floatValue == 0)
```

Comment: NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull floatValue]:
error is given @Cyrille

Comment: Yep, you should check for `NSNull` *before* unboxing.

Answer (score 2):

I've been checking if NSDecimalNumber was null using:

```
if (decimalNumber == nil)
```

This is working great for me.

Comment: This works in most cases but not, for instance, when observing a property or Core Data attribute. The change dictionary passed on by observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: may contain a null value that will not evaluate to 'nil'. Thus 'NSNumber *oldNumber = [change valueForKey:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey];' will pass the (oldNumber != nil) test but then something like 'oldNumber.integerValue' will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
            NSDictionary *regionDict = (NSDictionary *) region;
            NSNumber *lat;
            if([regionDict objectForKey:@"lat"] == [NSNull null])
            {
                lat = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                lat = [regionDict objectForKey:@"lat"];
            }
            NSNumber *lng;
            if([regionDict objectForKey:@"lng"] == [NSNull null] )
            {
                lng=0;
            }
            else
            {
            //[latitude addObject:lat];
                lng = [regionDict objectForKey:@"lng"];
            }
            //[longitude addObject:lng];


            if(lat.floatValue  == 0.00 && lng.floatValue == 0.00)
            {
                NSLog(@"%@%@%@",lat,lng,titles);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"%@%@%@",lat,lng,titles);
                CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
                coord.latitude =lat.doubleValue;
                coord.longitude =lng.doubleValue;
                MapViewAnnotation *annotation =[[MapViewAnnotation alloc]initWithTitle:titles AndCoordinate:coord];
                [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear what you want to check. Depending on your JSON data, you will get one of the following:

```
myObject == nil - the object isn't there at all. 
myObject == [NSNull null] - the JSON data is "null" without the quotes
myObject.doubleValue == 0.0 - the JSON data contained a number 0 or 0.0
```

Note that trying to read doubleValue will crash if the JSON data was "null", so that needs checking first. Comparing

```
myObject == [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.0]
```

isn't going to work, because that just compares object pointers. Would be a very huge coincidence if this was actually the same object.

Comment: `==` checks identity, but to check if to objects are equal it might only work in some edge cases (string literals). use `[myObject isEqualToNumber:@(0.0)]` instead.

Comment: I prefer to check for [myObject isEqual:[NSNull null]] vs. using ==, for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

```
[obj isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]
```